# Using python to parse a text file without delimiters

Tags: python

I have searched thoroughly, possibly with incorrect search terms, for a way to use Python to parse a text file WITHOUT the use of delimiters.  All prior discussion found assumes the use of the CSV library (with comma delimited text) but since the input file does not use a comma-delimited format, csv does not seem to be the correct library to use.

For example, I would like to parse the 18th to 29th text character of each line regardless of context.  The input file is general text, say, each line is 132 characters in length.

I could post an example input but don't see the point in it if the input is general text and is to be parsed without the use of any patterns to delimit.

Ideas?

Comment: For the 18-29 example, read each line in turn, and those with 18 or more characters, print the appropriate substring of each line as you read each line in turn.

Answer (score 0):

The [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module can be used to parse fixed-length format files. Simply construct a format string using the appropriate length modifier for the `s` format character.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line[18:30]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use something like this:

```
Res = [ ]
fo = open( filename) #open your file for reading ('r' by default)
for line in fo: # parse the file line by line
    Res.append( line[ 18 : 30 ]  ) # extract the desired text from the current line
fo.close()

print(Res)# exploit the extracted data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 18th to 29th characters of every line...

```
f = open(<path>, 'r')
results = [line[18:30] for line in f.readlines() if len(line) > 29]
f.close()
for r in results:
    print r
```